# How to include cinnamon via kickstart in CentOS 7

Tags: kickstart, centos7, rhel7

I'm trying to install cinnamon via kickstart in CentOS 7.

In previous versions of CentOS/RHEL there was the *%packages --resolvedeps* options

This option is no longer available.

I have the following for repos:

```
repo --name=epel --baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
repo --name=rdo-release --baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-juno/epel-7/
```

I also have:

```
%packages --ignoremissing
@core
epel-release
cinnamon
opencv-python
...
%end
```

Am I missing something?

The Screen Grab is below.

[image: VirtualBox Screen Capture]

Comment: Where is your CentOS base repo?

Comment: I think you are missing something important. Post the complete kickstart file.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/3YZ74AD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install from the installation DVD, which due to space constraints doesn't contain every possible package. To install packages that aren't on the DVD during installation, you'll need to do a network installation instead, generally from a local mirror accessible via NFS or HTTP, or a public mirror.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I added the CentOS-Base repo and all was well. Thank you.